# Как в заголовке поставить символ переноса строки?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="id" title='Номер документа' [width]="110" [headerClass]="{'myClass': true}">
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

Как в title прописать, чтобы выражение номер документа было на двух строчках, т.е. номер (перенос строки) документ.